# How does TF know what object you are finetuning for

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I am trying to improve mobilenet_v2's detection of boats with about 400 images I have annotated myself, but keep on getting an underfitted model when I freeze the graphs, (detections are random does not actually seem to be detecting rather just randomly placing an inference). I performed 20,000 steps and had a loss of 2.3.

I was wondering how TF knows that what I am training it on with my custom label map

ID:1

Name: 'boat'

Is the same as what it regards as a boat ( with an ID of 9) in the mscoco label map.

Or whether, by using an ID of 1, I am training the models' idea of what a person looks like to be a boat?

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Obviously, I'm confused as to the problem; where does this ID of `1` come into your process?

Comment: When running the pipeline for training you need to pass a label map, I was following: https://pythonprogramming.net/custom-objects-tracking-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/   However, he is not finetuning but rather adding a new parameter (mac & cheese) whereas I wish to improve the pre-trained mobilenet v2's detection of boats.

Comment: Okay; I'll have to leave this to someone with time to peruse the off-site materials.

Answer (score 0):

The model works with the category labels (numbers) you give it.  The string "boat" is only a translation for human convenience in reading the output.

If you have a model that has learned to identify a set of 40 images as class `9`, then giving it a very similar image that you insist is class `1` will confuse it.  Doing so prompts the model to elevate the importance of differences between the `9` boats and the new `1` boats.  If there *are* no significant differences, then the change in weights will find unintended features that *you* don't care about.

The result is a model that is much less effective.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I trained to 25,000 steps using 400 boat images using a label map containing: name: "m/019jd", ID: 9, display_name: "boat". As per the mscoco label map and it does not detect anything, In a 3 minute video of a boats it did not show a single inferrence.

Answer (score 0):

so I managed to figure out the issue.

We created the annotation tool from scratch and the issue that was causing underfitting whenever we trained regardless of the number of steps or various fixes I tried to implement was that **When creating bounding boxes there was no check to identify whether the xmin and ymin coordinates were less than the xmax and ymax** I did not realize this would be such a large issue but after creating a very simple check to ensure the coordinates are correct training ran smoothly.